# Simulate F2 + Enter in Excel to apply autoformatting logic (e.g. hyperlink)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

MS Excel 2013

I have a plain text file that was tab delimited that I opened in Excel.  One of the columns is a hyperlink.  If I hit F2 (edit cell) then Enter, it converts the hyerplink into one that is clickable.  Is there a way to automate this? e.g. highlight all the cells and tell it to autoformat them into a clickable hyperlink?

Comment: You could probably do it with a AutoHotkey script....

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2595692/3211023

Comment: @Calvin Very close duplicate...

Comment: @calvin ahh, nice find.  Ironically, I spend more time in SO than on SU, but didn't think to check there.